# Infimum of a set, not in the set.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $E$ consist of all the numbers $\frac1n$, where $n=1,2,3,\dots$ Then $\sup E = 1$, which is in $E$ and $\inf E=0$, which is not in $E$. - Rudin(Principles of mathematical Analysis)

This isn't true though is it? I feel as though there is no infimum, since $E$ tends towards $0$ as $n\to\infty$, but $0$, as said, isn't in $E$.

Is $\inf E$ truly equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathrm{inf}(E)$ equals $0$. The whole point of the careful definition of $\mathrm{inf}$ is that every non-empty set of real numbers that is bounded below has a (necessarily unique) infimum (in the real numbers). This is why we don't just call it $\mathrm{min}(E)$.

Comment: What did you read that makes you think the infimum must belong to the set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $(\inf E)\not\in E$.  Your example gets at the infimum of a set as compared to the minimum of a set.  The infimum is the greatest lower bound of elements in the set.  In the case that the infimum is in the set, it may also be called the minimum of the set.  (I.e., the minimum must be an element of the set.) The set in your example has no minimum.

Comment: This is a good answer. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The infimum and the supremum need not be contained in the set. I think he gives an example in Chapter 1, possibly that $E1 = (0,1)$ and $E2 = (0,1]$ and $E1 \neq E2$ but $sup(E1)=sup(E2)$. He may even have related it to the example with the set A such that $r^2 < 2$ and B such that $r^2 > 2$ for positive rationals r. These come straight from the definition of supremum and infimum.

The key part of the infimum definition for this purpose is that if there is any $x > inf(E)$, then it is  not a lower bound of E.